# How To Stick TPanel Component To dxSpreadSheet (DevExpress) Component

Tags: delphi, devexpress, panel, delphi-2010

I need to stick a panel to dxSpreadSheet's particular cell, anyways to achieves this ?

I remembering doing grouping on components in MS-Word, same thing I needed in my Delphi 2010 application.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "stick a panel". Could you elaborate, perhaps with an image.

Comment: I would like to place a panel inside the dxSpreadSheet from the range C1 to E6. And if I scroll down the dxSpreadSheet then this panel should stick to that area.I need to add buttons inside the dxSpreadSheet just like macro inside the Excel.

Comment: Do you need to add a panel, or do you need to add buttons?

Comment: If I could get buttons inside the cells i.e. one button per cell, that would be more than enough. Then on those button click event I need to write macro related code (macro code is in Excel) in Delphi. Currently I am loading Excel file inside the dxSpreadSheet directly but it doesn't support the macros, I need to have buttons in that specific range and then need to write code on each button click event.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask that instead since it's what you really want. Did you ask devexpress?

Comment: FWIW: The question is now where it belongs: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T261508